# How to store C# object data as XML using XML Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

Could somebody advise if XML Serialization is achievable with my design?

I have written the code for the core functionality for my 'System Administration' application. For Sprint 1 of my project, I have to store all data in a temporary XML data store which will be replaced using ADO.Net in Sprint 2.

I have looked into serializing classes using XML Serialization such as in below articles:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-2

I have the following classes which (I think) need to be stored as XML:

- A User class with multiple properties
- A UserAccessGroup class with a String property Name and a List of ints UserIDs
- A UserAdministration Class that holds a List of all User objects and one or more UserAccessGroup objects (constructor uses params UserAccessGroup[]). It has methods for adding/deleting users on the system, adding/deleting UserIDs from a UserAccessGroup.
- A UserVerification Class that holds a UserAdministration object and the UserAccessGroup object for the application being logged on to. It also has two ints for counting failed and successful logon attempts a method for logging on which returns true if all conditions are met, otherwise false.
- A ServiceRequest class with multiple properties
- A ServiceRequestTracker class that holds a list of all ServiceRequest objects and has methods for adding/deleting/editing them.

I have the below code in my Program file:

```
static void Main()
        {
            UserAccessGroup SystemAdmin_App = new UserAccessGroup("Admin Operators");
            UserAccessGroup Shareholder_App = new UserAccessGroup("Shareholders");
            UserAccessGroup Broker_App = new UserAccessGroup("Brokers");
            UserAccessGroup StockExMgr_App = new UserAccessGroup("StockExMgrs");

            UserIDGenerator IDGenerator = new UserIDGenerator();

            UserAdministration userAdmin = new UserAdministration(IDGenerator,
                SystemAdmin_App, Shareholder_App, Broker_App, StockExMgr_App);

            UserVerificationService userVerification = new UserVerificationService(
                userAdmin, SystemAdmin_App);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            LoginScreen myLoginScreen = new LoginScreen();
            Application.Run(myLoginScreen);
        }
```

Only now that I have finished writing all of my classes using TDD have I looked into storing object data as XML. I am finding it very confusing to apply XML Serialization to my design and I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this without completely re-designing my application from scratch?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using an existing XML serializer, it's usually enough to put the `[Serializable]` attribute on a class and pass your object to the serializer; especially if you only intend for the same application to deserialize the object later on. One caveat: You have to `[XmlIgnore]` any property that could cause circular references. E.g. if Parent has a Child property, and that Child object has a Parent property which references the same connection. Your serializer will get stuck in a loop and cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @Flater Thanks for the reply! I'm still unsure how to do serialize my objects. For example, UserAdministration contains a list of Users and has methods for adding/removing Users from the list. Say for example, I add a new user by calling the addUser method of UserAdministration. How does the new User object get added to the XML file?

Comment: Any set of classes can be serialized as long as the root element is not an array.  Your root element is userAdmin.  So you should serialize userAdmin and it will automatically create the xml for the other classes.

Comment: @MichaelHennigan: I will add an answer showing a basic serialization example for custom classes. How you store the data (separate file per class type, one big file, separate file per parent-child family, ...) is completely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion in comments, I'll give you a basic overview of how you can quickly (de)serialize custom classes.

For reference, here's your comment to which I'm replying:

> @Flater Thanks for the reply! I'm still unsure how to do serialize my objects. For example, UserAdministration contains a list of Users and has methods for adding/removing Users from the list. Say for example, I add a new user by calling the addUser method of UserAdministration. How does the new User object get added to the XML file?

---

I always use this helper class because it makes the code so much cleaner. I've copied it from the internet somewhere, potentially StackOverflow. I will credit the author once I know/remember who it is.

```
public static class SerializerHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="serializableObject"></param>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    public static void SerializeObject<T>(string filepath, T serializableObject)
    {
        if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                stream.Position = 0;
                xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                xmlDocument.Save(filepath);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an xml file into an object list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string filepath)
    {
        T objectOut = default(T);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)) return objectOut;

        try
        {
            string attributeXml = string.Empty;

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(filepath);
            string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

            using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                Type outType = typeof(T);

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                {
                    objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }

                read.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
        }

        return objectOut;
    }
}
```

Before I get to the usage examples, some tips so you know how to approach this:

- These methods will serialize a single object (of any type) to a given file. This can be a class `Foo`, a `List<Foo>`, or a custom made class that contains all the data you want to save `MyFooData`
- You cannot add to an existing file. When saving a file, **the old file will be overwritten**. I have not yet come across a use case where I needed to add to a file and couldn't just read the file's contents, change them, and store the whole object again. But I've only used it for small scale storage.
- XML serialization uses **public properties** and a **parameterless constructor**. So make sure the objects you want to store have both of these. It will not serialize private or protected properties; or public/private/protected class fields.
- The XML Serializer will automatically also serialize subclasses that are contained within (if they are public properties!). As far as I'm aware, it can go as deep as you want it to go. It will save *everything*.
- The XML serializer has a weakness to recursion. I will explain how to avoid recursion in the code examples.
- XML Serialization cannot (de)serialize `Dictionary<T1,T2>` or any `IEnumerable` that uses hashes for storage. However, if you want to store a `Dictionary<T1,T2>`, you **can** store it as a `List<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>`, which means it will retain your data; just not the internal hash that it uses for quick lookup.

**1 - The simplest example**

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public static void TestMethod()
{
    var myUser = new User() { Name = "John", Email = "John@john.com" };

    //Save to file
    SerializerHelper.SerializeObject(@"C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt", myUser);

    //Read from file
    var myUserReloaded = SerializerHelper.DeSerializeObject<User>(@"C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt");
}
```

Take note of the `[Serializable]` attribute on the `User` class. This is usually the only change that you need to make to your classes to make this work.

**2 - Avoiding recursion and stack overflows**

As mentioned in the tips, this serialization has a weakness to recursion. This can happen when classes refer to eachother in both directions.

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Manager Boss {get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Manager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User FavoriteEmployee {get; set; }
}

public static void TestMethod()
{
    var userJohn = new User() { Name = "John", Email = "John@john.com" };
    var managerMark = new Manager() { Name = "Mark" };

    managerMark.FavoriteEmployee = userJohn;
    userJohn.Boss = managerMark;

    //Save to file
    SerializerHelper.SerializeObject(@"C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt", userJohn);

    //Read from file
    var userJohnReloaded = SerializerHelper.DeSerializeObject<User>(@"C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt");
}
```

You will get a stack overflow exception when saving the file, because the serializer gets stuck in an infinite loop.

The serializer tries to write all of `userJohn`'s properties to the file. When it gets to the `Boss` property, it notices that it is a serializable object and will begin serializing all of `managerMark`'s properties. When it gets to the `FavoriteEmployee` property, it notices that it is a serializable object and will begin serializing all of `userJohn`'s properties. When it...

You can prevent this from happening by using the [XmlIgnore] attribute on one of the two properties (or both, if you want to be really secure).

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Manager Boss {get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Manager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public User FavoriteEmployee {get; set; }
}
```

The serializer tries to write all of `userJohn`'s properties to the file. When it gets to the `Boss` property, it notices that it is a serializable object and will begin serializing all of `managerMark`'s properties. When it gets to the `FavoriteEmployee` property, it notices that this property is marked `[XmlIgnore]` and it will not attempt to serialize what is contained within.

---

I hope this answer is what you were looking for.

---

**EDIT** I forgot a big caveat.

Let's say we are storing a `List<Child>` with two `Child` objects in it. Both `Child` objects have a `Parent` property, and it just so happens that both children are referencing the same `Parent` (same object in memory).

**If I store the** `Parent` (including a list of its children) it will serialize our `Parent` which will contain both `Child` objects. When deserializing, you will again have a singular `Parent` object and the two `Child` objects you started with.

**If I store the** `List<Child>` (including their parent), it will serialize the `Parent` for both `Child` objects. However, when deserializing, both `Parent` objects will be deserialized **but they will be separate objects in memory**.

As you can see, there could be a potential bug here if you are expecting both children to refer to the same `Parent` (as an object in memory). For this reason, I have a personal rule about how to use the serialization, and where to put the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute.

Children (`IEnumerable<Foo>`) get serialized, parents (`Foo`) do not. This allows me to store an entire tree in one go.

This means that I have to **store the parent** (and automatically have its children be serialized too), and I can only store the child without its reference to its parent (unless you store a `ParentId` key in the `Child`).

By doing it this way, you ensure that you won't create a multitude of `Parent` objects through deserialization, because every object only gets mentioned **once** in the XML file.

---

**Edit**

I forgot to add the `SerializerHelper.` to the method calls. Fixed now.

Comment: Or you could try making `FavoriteEmployee` and `Boss` ids referring to use User id.

Comment: @Tvde1: Yes. However, if you only store the ID of the boss, then you will still need to serialize the boss object separately. And when loading the data again, you will have to manually fill in the `Boss` property based on the ID you stored. If you instead still serialize the object (but only one way, like in my example), then the deserialization will immediately fill in the `Boss` property with the needed object and its data. My personal rule is: children (the IEnumerable references) get serialized, parents (singular references) do not. This allows me to store an entire tree in one go.

Comment: @Flater Thanks so much for the answer, it's really comprehensive! I think I'll be able to apply this to my application now (probably with some trial and error!).

Comment: @MichaelHennigan: It's surprisingly easy to work with :) The caveats I've mentioned are situational and don't occur for simple use cases. I've just collected them over years of using the same snippet over and over.

Comment: @Flater In your simple example, I presume I will have to first create a SerializeHelper object and then call the SerializeObject method such as MySerializeHelper.SerializeObject(@"C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt", userJohn)?

Comment: @MichaelHennigan: Nope. They are static methods. All you need to do is supply the filename and the object. Instantiating the object is unnecessary as there is no "saved" data in between operations on the SerializerHelper.

Comment: But I did just see an error in my simple code sample. Am correcting it now.

Comment: Edited the question. You need to call `SerializerHelper.SerializeObject(..)` instead of just `SerializeObject(..)` (same for DeserializeObject). That mistake was mine; I had typed the code example inside the `SerializerHelper` class which meant that the `SerializerHelper.` prefix is not necessary :) Outside of the `SerializerHelper` (where you would actually use it), **it is necessary**. But you still do not need to create an instance of `SerializerHelper` as the methods are static and therefore already available.

Comment: @Flater One last question (I really do hope it's the last one!): I have applied your solution to my code so that ServiceRequestTracker contains a List<ServiceRequest> and a RequestIDGenerator. I have added a constructor for ServiceRequestTracker which sets the list of service requests to SerializerHelper.DeserializeObject(@"C\.....ServiceRequests.xml") and same for the RequestIDGenerator. This is so that every time the application is run, it will load the latest data from the XML files. However, the first time I run the code, the XML files will not exist yet. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Flater I was thinking maybe if I manually create the XML files in Notepad++ that it would solve the problem but now I have got stuck as I'm not sure how an empty list of service requests would translate into XML

Comment: @MichaelHennigan: Although it is possible to create the XML files manually, I would advise against it. The key part here is that the **serializer** (and nothing or noone else) is responsible for the (de)serialization. We don't need to know **how** (or in what format) things get serialized; we just need the serializer to be able to parse the files that the serializer wrote **himself**. My suggestion is to make a small console application that creates the object in memory and stores it to a file. You can then use that file in any application you want.